# Mongo aggregate - How to use $match and $group with object array fields?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have the following datastructure of documents in my `pr` collection for which I want to use `$group` in combination with `$avg` to get some averages of specific fields:

First example doc:

```
   {
    "_id" : "MRoPGeY7atYiPm5nW",
    "HO" : "dfd>prZKfHepCR7jEB2Lk",
    "SP" : 22,
    "pInfos" : [ 
        {
            "pId" : "A",
            "pK" : "B"
        }
    ],
    "Fs" : {
        "CC" : {
            "Output" : {
                "CCOutput" : 24,
                "CCOutput2" : 26
            },
            "FsResult" : 28
        }
    },
    "SPS" : 30
}
```

Second example doc:

```
 {
        "_id" : "AAoPGeY7atYiPm5nW",
        "HO" : "dfd>prZKfHepCR7jEB2Lk",
        "SP" : 12,
        "pInfos" : [ 
            {
                "pId" : "A",
                "pK" : "B"
            }
        ],
        "Fs" : {
            "CC" : {
                "Output" : {
                    "CCOutput" : 24,
                    "CCOutput2" : 26
                },
                "FsResult" : 28
            }
        },
        "SPS" : 30
    }
```

There are several more docs with the same structure. I now need to get the averages of `SP` for all docs with the same `HO` field. I am using the meteorhacks package to be able to use mongos aggregate with meteor, so maybe my aggregate query looks quite different than native. I get the values with this query:

```
pr.aggregate(

{ $match: { HO: "dfd>prZKfHepCR7jEB2Lk"} },
{ $group: { _id: '$HO', total: { $avg: '$SP' } } },
{ $project: {total:1, _id:0 } }

);
```

I get the result I want:

```
[ {_id: 'dfd>prZKfHepCR7jEB2Lk', total: 17 } ]
```

However, I am not able to get the averages of the nested fields like `CCOutput` or `FsResult` from all docs with the same `HO` field. Additionally it is not clear for me, how I can use a nested field like `pK` for `$match`, because I also need the averages of `SP`, `CCOutput` and `FsResult` for all docs which have the same `pK` field for example.

I think the common (Mongo native) way of how to use `$match` and `$group` with nested fields would also work with meteorhacks.

Comment: your query is not correct syntatically

Comment: The query in the question for which I get the result works by using the meteorhacks:aggregate package which I need to use mongos aggregate functions within the meteor framework.

Comment: ah Ohk. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the dotted notation :

```
pr.aggregate([
    {$match: {HO: "dfd>prZKfHepCR7jEB2Lk"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$HO", total: {$avg: "$SP"}, totalCCoutput: {$avg: "$Fs.CC.Output.CCoutput"}, totalFs: {$avg: "$Fs.CC.FsResult"}}}
]);
```

I wrote it like if I use the Nodejs Mongo Driver, but I think this query will work

Comment: Nice, but I think (at least in my case) there needs to be a "$" before the "Fs.CC.Output.CCOutput". After adding that "$" it works, many thanks! Do you maybe also know of how to use the "pK" field for $match to get the $avg of all docs which have the same pK field? It crashed when I use pInfos.pK or pInfos.0.pK...That would be great!

Comment: Thanks for the $ character, I've juste edited the answer. For your question about the pk field, did you try with: `$match: {"pInfos.pk": "what you want"}` ? it should work

Comment: Perfect! I just forgot the "" for the dot notation. So your solution with "pInfos.pK": "what you want" works fine, while pInfos.pK : "what you want" fails in my case. Many thanks :)